# jquery: aborting ajax will trigger done or fail?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't understand a thing about $.ajax, .done and .fail

I start my ajax call, assigning this to a variabile.

At next ajax call i test if variable is defined, and then i call abort.

I'm not able to undertsand if .abort() causes execution of .done or not.

If it causes .done, how to check status and detect aborted call ?

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR :

> In particular, calling .abort() on the object will halt the request before it completes.

... so I understand that .done will not be fired after a .abort, right ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second argument to the `fail` callback is `textStatus`, for an aborted request that should be `"abort"`. I wouldn't expect the `done` callback to be fired.

Answer (score -2):

After "abort", it will call "done"(more specifically, `done(0, statusText || "abort")`) as long as no exception happens(which can be verified from the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js)). This is reasonable in that the abort action is issued by the user, and the `abort` **IS done** without failure.

Comment: A closer look at the source code shows it calls `fail` and not `done`. The `done` you see being called is not the callback but an internal function: `// Callback for when everything is done`. It has a check `// If successful, handle type chaining` implemented as `if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 )` whose else part says `// We extract error from statusText then normalize statusText and status for non-aborts`.